# how to refresh one row without reloading full page in jquery and ajax while performing insertion\deletion\edit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

My jquery code is

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {           
        $("#body").on("click", ".button", function () {
            var name = $("#name").val();
            var lname = $("#lname").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var mob = $("#mob").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: "add.jsp",
                type: "post",
                data: {
                    name: name,
                    lname: lname,
                    email: email,
                    mob: mob,
                    id: i,
                    update: isUpdating ? 1 : 2,
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    isUpdating = false;
                    location.reload();                   
                    get(data);
                }
            })
        });
        function get() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "select.jsp",
                type: "post",
                datatype:"json",
                success: function (data) {
                    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                    for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
                        $("#tbody").append("<tr><td>" + obj[i].id + "</td><td>" + obj[i].name + "</td><td>" + obj[i].lname + "</td><td>" + obj[i].email + "</td><td>" + obj[i].mob + "</td><td>" + '<input type="button" class="edit" value="edit">' + "</td><td>" + '<input type="button" class="delete" value="delete">'+ "</td></tr>");
                     }
                 }
             })
         }
         get();
     });
 </script>
```

The code above will refresh the page completely because here I am using `location.reload();`. Help me to update only the selected rows while performing insertion or deletion or editing.

My html code is as follows

```
<body>
  <table border="1" style="background-color:  #c1c0c0;margin-left: 500px;">
    <tbody id="tbody">
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>last name</th>
        <th>email</th>
        <th>mobile</th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

the html code also contains a form submit page above the table body

Comment: You have to modify the DOM instead of reloading the page in your success callback function. I don't know you html so I can't help much further, but I supouse it's something similar to your success callback in the get method. You have to select the correct row and modify it with a jQuery expression.

Comment: remove  `location.reload();`  and add  `$("#tbody").empty();`

Comment: $("#tbody").empty();  this code works,but it refreshes page as same as location.reload

Answer (score 0):

First, remove `location.reload();`.

I see you have tried to use `get(data)` too, but your get function is an ajax call that doesn't admit any argument.

I suggest you to extract the post success function to a new function, and call it in post and get success functions:

```
function writeData(data){

    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
        $("#tbody").append("<tr><td>" + obj[i].id + "</td><td>" + obj[i].name + "</td><td>" + obj[i].lname + "</td><td>" + obj[i].email + "</td><td>" + obj[i].mob + "</td><td>" + '<input type="button" class="edit" value="edit">' + "</td><td>" + '<input type="button" class="delete" value="delete">'+ "</td></tr>");
     }
}
```

So both of your success functions can use it as follow:

```
success: function (data) {
             // ... do stuff
             writeData(data);
         }
```

Also, in this example you have exactly one row, but in case of having more rows this will not work. You have to change the html and add an id to each row (the data id, for example) and then select the row that you are going to change with jQuery instead of all the table.